# Japanese style or themed accommodation in Melbourne

Tags: australia, accommodation, culture, melbourne, ryokans

What Japanese-style or Japanese-themed accommodation is available in Melbourne?

I tried doing a search for ryokans in Melbourne, and while I've found a number of ryokans in countryside Victoria, which is the logical place to have ryokans, I haven't found any in Melbourne itself. [Shizuka Ryokan](http://shizuka.com.au/) is in the [Daylesford/Hepburn Springs area](http://shizuka.com.au/region/), as is [Daruma Ryokan](http://www.daruma.com.au/), while [Japanese Mountain Retreat](http://www.japanesemountainretreat.com.au/) (billed as a blend of ryokan culture and modern architecture) is in the Yarra Valley/Dandenong Ranges area. [Japanese Slipper](http://www.japaneseslipper.com.au/), which described itself as having "traditional and authentic simplicity" but doesn't call itself a ryokan, is 40 minutes from the CBD and close to the Dandenong Ranges.

Doing a search for minshukus in Melbourne didn't get any relevant results.

I'm willing to be very broad in my definition of Japanese style or Japanese themed accommodation. Anything with [tatami or a futon](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18295/are-inexpensive-ryokans-inauthentic) would definitely count. Even a backpacker's hostel which is heavily Japanese themed would be ok, even though hostels are not very traditional. It should have reasonably good non-car transport access to the CBD, as I anticipate having dinner or going out to the pub in the CBD.

Comment: I tried looking for a Japanese-owned downtown hotel, but didn't find anything. 25 years ago, there was one in Sydney.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, **none**.

Obviously I can't prove a negative, but I lived in Melbourne 2010-2013 and became quite familiar with the Japanese community and the facilities available.  The Japanese community is quite small (~5,000 people), most of that essentially transient (students & working holidays), and the small expat population is shrinking now that the plug has been pulled on car manufacturing in Victoria.  So there's little demand, and indeed the facilities that you list are geared almost entirely towards locals and tourists looking for an "exotic" experience.

See also [Japan in Melbourne](http://www.japaninmelbourne.com.au/), which lists of a whole bunch of Japanese-themed places and events, but no accommodation.