# Should we check out from hotel?

Tags: hotels, check-in, etiquette

I got a hotel card now. My smart gf says I do not need to check out.

She said just throw away the card that the hotel will automatically check me out.

The card is cheap and replaceable.

I fear that if I don't check out, debt collector will come to my home and says hello, you have stayed in our hotel for 5 years and you owe use these bills.

My gf says it won't happen.

Which one is right?

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have paid all the charges associated with your stay?

Comment: Your gf is right.

Comment: If you feel like checking out why don’t you checkout?

Comment: If you want to help the environment at least leave the card in the room.

Comment: @HankyPanky There may be a queue and they may need to catch a train.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused why this question stands at -4 but [the duplicate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/120404) stands at +63.

Comment: Welcome new user!  Great question.  Why would this question be downvoted?  Bizarre.

Comment: Your GF is totally correct (she is both smart and pretty!)  You havent had to check out of hotels for years.  Just leave .. walk off!  Enjoy!

Comment: @Fattie great question? Are you joking? It's about specific hotel's policy, without even specifying what hotel it it about...

Answer (score 9):

Many hotels, especially large corporate chain hotels, have an "express checkout" service where they'll put a copy of your bill under your door and invite you to simply leave without checking out if all is ok, with the balance of the charges billed to your credit card on file. Sometimes you can officially "check out" from your telephone or in-room TV. See [In US hotels, what happens if you skip checkout and just leave the hotel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/120404).

They certainly aren't going to think you've stayed for five years if you haven't checked out. At the end of your stay, they'll come to clean your room, notice you're gone, and take care of it for you. But some hotels, especially smaller hotels, do want you to check out.

So if you're unsure about the hotel's policy, want a complete copy of your bill, or just want the peace of mind that your business with the hotel is finished, there's absolutely no harm in stopping at the front desk to check out.

Comment: Even with express checkout, it is helpful to other guests to inform the front desk when you are leaving. Many hotels try to clean vacated rooms as early as possible to allow early check-in.

Comment: If you are still in the hotel, leave the key card at the front desk, either in the hands of staff or in a container there for that reason,

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan To that effect one could leave the door open.

Comment: @gerrit That only helps if someone happens to see it. Also, the hotel would hold the guest responsible for any theft or damage due to the door being left open and unattended. Calling the front desk definitely informs the hotel, and the room can be left locked.